# Nginx Redirect to root for nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am running `nginx` which is listening on port number 9000.

The redirect rules are as follows:

1. Anything to `/` should go to `index.html`.
2. Anything to `/rest` should forward the request to background service.
3. Anything apart from `rule 1` and `rule 2` should forward to `rule 1` or index.html

My sample `nginx` configuration file is as follows:

```
 server {
 listen       9000;
 server_name  localhost;

 location / {
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index  index.html index.htm;
 }

 error_page 404 403 405 500 502 503 504 = @notfound;

 location /rest {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:12000;
 }

 location @notfound {
     return 301 http://localhost/;
 }
}
```

My redirect is not working properly, and it will redirect to `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost:9000`.

Can anybody point out where am I doing the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return 301 http://localhost/;` should be `return 301 http://localhost:9000/;`

Comment: I tried, but the issue is if I use an invalid url like `http://localhost:9000/1234` ,then it is redirecting me to index page, but the url is not changing to `http://localhost:9000`, instead it is still  `http://localhost:9000/1234`.

Comment: You need to also change `location / {` to `location = / {`

Comment: can I give the location directive instead of `http://localhost:9000`, like `location @notfound {
        return 301 /;
    }`

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: when I tried to redirect `@notfound` to `return 301 /;`, the page is getting redirected to `http://localhost` and not to  `http://localhost:9000`

Comment: The try with `return 301 http://$host;` or `return 301 http://$HTTP_host;`